# make a side menu type accordion with angular 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to implement an accordion side-menu using Bootstrap but i can't seem to get it right, I imported the bootrap in app.component i can see that it is well imported and the accordion appear just fine , But the sub-menus don't appear, I click on item 1 per exemple it shows in the url as target but nothing is shown.
Thank you . 
this is the Bootstrap class im based on "list-group-item".

 here is an exemple that doesn't collapse under angular

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group</a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you might have missed `jquery` library

Comment: thank you,just did and still no dropdowns just the main menus

Comment: can you create a working demo in a plunker?

Comment: i'm not familiar with that but i will try

Comment: @AyoubIdelhoussain you can use this library http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

Comment: done that too but when i click on "Collapsible list group" like in the exemple above it doesn't come down